# ssrs merging row inside column and row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Can i (dynamically?)merge cells inside row and group column, or make a header/total below it? Have tried a lot of methods, but without success.

this is table what i've configured

[image1](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/29/3838933f538cc76a9a6d48543021dfad-full.png)

result i get

[image2](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/29/a6b221981a386af2c448c010365aca3b-full.png)

resuil i want to see

[image3](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/29/607a6074f963906d637fae834073aec1-full.png)

i want this fields "text1", "text2" to be merged. Please note, this field inside column and row group.

Is it possible? Tried to paste tablix inside textbox. but it duplicates for every column group record. Tried setting it's visibility. But i need text inside.

Answer (score 0):

Just chose all the tablix cells you want to merge, then right click with the mouse and **Merge Cells**. If its not working the first time, empty the cells and try it again.

Comment: Sorry, but it not works, This report returning days of the month, and duplicates  this row for every record in dataset. And i cant merge only one cell :) [image](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/29/a91dd53150da853119f460404b46066e-full.png) This field inside column and row group/

Comment: If you want to merge cells you need to select more then one cell and then right click. If you want to display two field values in one cell you can use a expression like this: `=Fields!FirstField.Value & " | " & Fields!SecondField.Value`

Comment: Excuse me, i can be not enough clear, but have you took view at pictures in first message? This text row inside row and column group. this is not simple text fields that i can select and merge. this fields should be like header for above rows. But the problem is that it placed in group, and can be placed deep inside row and column group. and duplicates for every record in dataset.

Comment: I think I know now what you want. But what you want is not possbile because you use a matrix. The top brakets indicates that you group on columns after your numbers `1, ...5`. What you could do is to use a tablix instead of a matrix and just group after your employee numbers and then put the colums `1, ..., 5` static in your tablix. This way you can merge the text.

Comment: thats great you got it, thanks) also tried this method. but the problem that i need to put 31 numbers (days of month), and use expression in each textbox. i have 31 days x 10 rows with expr. and totally about 100 records of main group. it takes 10-20 mins to execute it.

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is, when you use the matrix like in your picture without the text. Then you add a second dataset which includes the text. Then add a column to your matrix and join the text (with `Lookup()` function and a key) to your tablix column.